# How to access the user's facebook account? OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: objective-c, facebook, macos, cocoa, acaccount

I'm using the code from WWDC to access the user's facebook account:

```
self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [self.accountStore
                                      accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
[self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType
                             withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {
                                 if (granted) {
                                     NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore
                                                          accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];
                                     self.facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
                                 } else {
                                     // Fail gracefully...
                                 }
                             }];
```

but it gives me error on the `requestAccessToAccountsWithType:withCompletionHandler:`.
[image]
How can I access the user's facebook account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook support was only added in 10.8.2. Are you using 10.8.2 yet? If so, *what specific error code are you getting*? We're not mind-readers.

---

If you *read the headers* as you're supposed to do, you'll see that `-requestAccessToAccountsWithType:withCompletionHandler:` does not exist on Mac, and is deprecated on iOS. You should be using `-requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:completion:`.

Comment: @PedroVieira: See my updated answer. The method does not exist.

Comment: @PedroVieira: Read the documentation.